# How to change the transform position of an instantiated GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Very basic beginner question: I'm making a brick breaker Unity game and I want my instantiated ball to spawn on the paddle and follow the paddle until I click my mouse. I'm expecting my code to work, but it just spawns a ball and does not follow the paddle around when instantiated. I've tried putting this code on my ball prefab script, but I am unable to reference the GameObject paddle from the prefab.

```
public bool isActive;
public GameObject ball;
public GameObject paddle;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    isActive = false;
    SpawnBall();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (isActive == false)
    {
        ball.transform.position = new Vector2(paddle.transform.position.x, paddle.transform.position.y);
    }
}
private void SpawnBall()
{
    // spawn a ball on top of the paddle
    Instantiate(ball, new Vector2(paddle.transform.position.x, paddle.transform.position.y + 0.4f), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Instantiate returns the new instance you have just created. That's the thing you want to move in your update. What you're currently doing is trying to move the original object, not the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Insatiate overload which takes in the transform of the parent:

`Instantiate(Object original, Vector2 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);`

So you could do this:

`Instantiate(ball, new Vector2(paddle.transform.position.x, paddle.transform.position.y + 0.4f), Quaternion.identity, paddle.Transform)`